# Reading from firebase inside a cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone help me determine why firebase isn't returning the value from a cloud function?
It seems like reading from on database change is simple, but when doing a http on request, firebase functions just hangs and finally times out.

```
exports.getTotalPrice = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var data = "";
   req.on('data', function(chunk){ data += chunk})
   req.on('end', function(){
       req.rawBody = data;
       req.jsonBody = JSON.parse(data);
       res.end(next(req.jsonBody));
   })
});
function next(json) {
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < json.products.length; i++) {
    //Get product by UPC
    console.log(order.products[i].upc);
    codeRef.orderByKey()
      .equalTo(order.products[i].upc)
        .once('value', function(snap) {
          console.log(snap.val()); // returns `null`
          return (snap.val()[0].msrp);
    })
    //Multiply the price of the product by the quantity
    console.log(order.products[i].quantity);

    //add it to the total price
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your reference to the database?

Comment: Since Stack Overflow isn't a consulting service, or a troubleshooting tool, it's important to start with an mcve. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Often, simply reducing scope until it works will reveal the answer, rather than a lot of guesswork in community channels. For example, the queries and `for(i) {...}` loop and  many other things can be removed from this question to clarify the problem set and find the source of the issue, it's also missing crucial details like how `codeRef` gets created.

Comment: Why are we using a function call to fetch Realtime Database data when it already provides a REST API that can be queried directly, SDKs for your clients' platforms, and security rules to control access? Something here doesn't jive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running several asynchronous functions but you aren't informing your function when they are done. The function needs to return a promise to succeed here.

Note also that if the database call fails, it's going to do so silently here. So you should capture errors and report those as well.

Note also that you're storing your distributed JSON data as arrays, which you [probably shouldn't](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Note also that you're using `.orderByKey().equalTo()` when you could just be using `.child(upc)`.

So what you've essentially got here is a mess. You need to spend some time in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and [samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/)--you're going to spend a lot of time thrashing like this if you don't.

For a starting point, reduce your code set to the simplest use case runs as expected:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.testDbOp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return admin.database()
     .ref('/foo')
     .once('value')
     .then(snap => res.send(JSON.stringify(snap.val()))
     .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```

Once you have that working, if you want to fetch several values asynchronously, you can do that with Promise.all(), something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.testDbOp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const promises = [];
  const output = {};
  const jsonData = {....};
  jsonData.products.forEach(product => {
     promises.push( codeRef.child(product.upc).once('value')
       .then(snap => output[product.upc] = snap.val()[0].msrp);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are calling the database at all. I only see `functions.https.onRequest()` which is a http trigger https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events.

If you wanted to call the database it would have to be something more like `functions.database.ref('/').onWrite(event => {})` so that it references the database https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events.

onWrite refers to any kind of change at that point in the database, not just writing to the database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But, you listed(much like the google docs list) a reference to .onWrite, I can very easily get data from on write, It is getting data without a separate database interaction that is needed. It must be possible, maybe i am just not getting it. Because I am triggering this from a http request, it can't rely on a database transaction to previously occur. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: If you're looking to make changes to the Database based on an http trigger, then you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to access the Database. 
See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/
You can also see it in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzEgwiSs-M

Comment: @Kevin192291 I don't understand what you mean when you say you want to get 'data without a separate database interaction'. How could you get data from the database without interacting with it? Can you please clarify what you mean by database interaction. Even if you use the firebase rest api or the admin sdk referred to above, you still have to interact with the db to get the data.